# React native - animating the blurRadius of an Image

Tags: animation, reactjs, react-native

I have a "cover" image for the top of one of my views that i'd love to be able to blur out as you scroll it out of view as a cool effect.

My state contains a `blurRadius` property, which i am binding to the `blurRadius={this.state.blurRadius}` prop on my `<Image>` component.

I have a `<ScrollView>` and am monitoring when it's scrolled with `onScroll`, where i am calling `setState({blurRadius: value})` - `value` being the distance that you've scrolled the view.

I've also set the `scrollEventThrottle={30}` prop on the scrollview so that i'm receiving the event regularly as the user scrolls.

The issue seems to be that the blurRadius updates but after a significant delay - and only to the maximum value. Am i missing something in order to make the image apply the new blurRadius with every call of `setState`?

Could it be that the image is just too large?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `setNativeProps` instead of `setState` to see if the performance improves. You just need to give your `Image` a `ref`.

```
this.refs.myImage.setNativeProps({ blurRadius: myValue });
```

Reducing the image size would also help as it would not need to blur as many pixels.

Comment: blurRadius with scrolling is still very very choppy/delayed.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `setState` to set anything as a response to onScroll, as this leads to poor performance. The reason is that the whole view will rerender for every call to setState, which leads to "view thrashing".

Instead, you should use the [Animated API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html), as this 'declares' the animation to the native UI thread, thus avoiding rerenders.

Brent Vatne (from the Expo team) gives a great explanation of Animated as well as a concrete example of animations as a response to `onScroll` events in `ScrollView` [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZCriZRuaow)

Hope it helps someone :-)